Execute code all the time while mouse button is held
Is there any way to execute python code only while the right mouse button is held? If the button becomes up, the code should interrupt immediately.
I tried to use the pynput library but the pressed parameter does not work in the while loop. It works right without while loop: prints correct message on "mouse right down" and "mouse right up" events. But with while it starts and endless loop and does not stop when the mouse button becomes up.
Any solution is appreciated, not only pynput library.
from pynput import mouse

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    if button == mouse.Button.right:
        if pressed:
            print(pressed)
            # Makes the problem:
            # Endless Print here. Even if mouse button becomes up
            while pressed:
                print("Executing code...") 
        else:
            print(pressed)

listener = mouse.Listener(on_click=on_click)
listener.start()
listener.join()


The reason why your code keeps indefinitely printing even after your mouse right click is up is because of your while loop.
You begin a loop when you call start() on listener so that it can keep checking for input. With your function, it is able to pick up right clicks. However, when it does detect a right click, it runs your while loop.
Here's how a while loop works. As you can see in the examples, to stop the while loop you need to have code inside of it that change the value it is checking or use break. In your case, since the input detection is already a while loop, you don't need to use another one.
Here's the fixed code:
from pynput import mouse

held = False #Variable to change when held.

#If you've tested pynput, you'll know that everytime you right click it will count
#it as two clicks, one on-click and one on-release. Because of this, we can change
#this variable to `True` after the first click and `False` after the second one.

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    global held #call global to get the variable `held` from inside a function
    if button == mouse.Button.right:
        if held:
            held = False
        else:
            held = True

    else: print('No Right Click Detected')

    if held:
        print('Executing code…') #code to execute when variable `held` is `True`

listener = mouse.Listener(on_click=on_click) #Pass your function to the listener's while loop
listener.start()
listener.join()


At last, I found the answer. keventhen4 answer had right direction but not enough information. The key is creating a global variable and check it's value, changing it every time pressed is changed. If you have a class, global variable can be changed to class field self.is_button_held:
        is_button_held = False

        def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
            global is_button_held
            if button == mouse.Button.right:  # Check for the left mouse button
                is_button_held = pressed
                if pressed:
                    print("Right mouse button pressed.")
                else:
                    print("Right mouse button released.")

        # Set up the listener
        with mouse.Listener(on_click=on_click) as listener:
            print("Listening for mouse events. Press Ctrl+C to stop.")
            try:
                while True:
                    global is_button_held
                    if is_button_held:
                        print("Right mouse button is being held down.")
                    time.sleep(0.1)  # Check every 100 ms
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                print("Stopped listening.")
                listener.stop()

